# Do I post an answer fixing wrong reasoning?

Tags: discussion

Recently I accepted an answer with partially wrong reasoning for 1 hint, but a correct solution, and correct reasoning on the others.

Now I have a small question: Should I make an answer posting the correct reasoning to the puzzle?

[Here is my specific case](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/29579/18770). In this answer the user has correctly guessed the answer, and correctly reasoned all hints except the third.

Answer (score 2):

One possible choice is:

If the answer was already to your satisfaction, except for that one point, simply edit the answer that you've marked correct and fix the detail that you find flawed, so that the answer is completely correct.

Comment: I don't find it exactly "flawed", just one of the hints wasn't solved the way I intended it to be. I've edited my specific case in now (small world, it's your answer :D).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question for [my case](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/29802/20538).
I chose to add a comment with the correct answer (written in rot13), and then accepted the answer.
I left it to the user to choose whether they wanted to edit their answer to make it fully correct.

Comment: That was me. But I don't know anything about rot13, and therefore has no possibility to actually edit my answer...

Comment: Ah.  I didn't know much about rot13 earlier either, but it seemed to be  used quite frequently on this site (including in a preceding comment to your answer).  So I used wolframalpha.com to do the encoding; you could try it too.  ;)

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that if, for whatever reason, the person elects not to update the answer, then you have an answer, checkmarked, to the puzzle that is not completely correct, for someone looking at it, later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could either comment or answer.

**Comment** if only one or two clues are wrong. The poster will probably see your comment, see that your comment is correct (maybe), and change the answer with attribution to those clues to you. This means the answer can be changed to become 100 percent correct in your eyes.

**Answer** if the answer is mostly, if not entirely wrong. You could have the same conclusion, but also the better (and correct) solutions to the clues given.

In your case, add an comment as only one clue is incorrect, the rest is correct.